# idAttribute not being set when fetching a collection

Tags: backbone.js

I am fetching a mongodb collection from server using backbone collection. Since the ids are stored as '_id', I used idAttribute to map it to '_id'.

```
(function(){
  var PlaceModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "_id",
  });
  var PlaceCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "http://localhost:9090/places",
    initialize: function(options){
      var that = this;
      this.fetch({
        success: function(){
          console.log("Success!", that.toJSON());
        },
        error: function(){
          console.log("Error");
        }
      });
    }
  });

  var place = new PlaceCollection({model:PlaceModel});

}());
```

But later on when I try to access the model's 'idAttribute' when it's time to DELETE an entry, it returns 'id' instead of '_id', which means this.model.isNew() from the view returns 'true' for all the records fetched from the server. Therefore I cannot DELETE nor PUT an entry to the server.

However if I set the idAttribute using prototype like this (instead of inside the PlaceModel definition):

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.idAttribute = "_id";
```

Then it correctly maps the idAttribute to '_id', and everything works. What might be happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you say this:

```
var place = new PlaceCollection({model:PlaceModel});
```

That's the same, more or less, as saying this:

```
var o     = new Backbone.Model({ model: PlaceModel });
var place = new PlaceCollection([ o ]);
```

You're not setting the collection "class"'s [`model`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model) property, you're just creating a collection with one model in it (a plain `Backbone.Model` instance, not a `PlaceModel`) and that model has a `model` attribute with value `PlaceModel`.

So, given all that, the collection has no idea that its model is supposed to have `idAttribute: "_id"` or even that its model is supposed to be a `PlaceModel`. You want to see the `model` when you create `PlaceCollection`, not when you create `place`:

```
var PlaceCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: "http://localhost:9090/places",
  model: PlaceModel,
  //...
});

var place = new PlaceCollection;
```